# Excel highest open interest change strike and type needed

Tags: excel-2010

```
Stocks name Strike  Type    Date        Open interest change            Name of stock   Open Interest mover strike today    Type
YESBANK     680 CE          1/12/2016                                 YESBANK       680 CE
YESBANK     680 CE          1/13/2016   -1400                         ADANIPORTS    210 CE
YESBANK     680 CE          1/19/2016   3500                    
YESBANK     680 CE          1/12/2016   72800                   
YESBANK     680 CE          1/13/2016   16800                   
YESBANK     680 CE          1/14/2016   19600                   
YESBANK     680 CE          1/15/2016   19600                   
YESBANK     680 CE          1/18/2016   39900                   
YESBANK     680 CE          1/19/2016   5000000                 
YESBANK     680 PE          1/12/2016                       
YESBANK     680 PE          1/13/2016   700                 
YESBANK     680 PE          1/15/2016   -1400                   
YESBANK     680 PE          1/18/2016   7000                    
YESBANK     680 PE          1/19/2016   -700                    
YESBANK     680 PE          1/12/2016   40600                   
YESBANK     680 PE          1/13/2016   -29400                  
YESBANK     680 PE          1/14/2016   6300                    
YESBANK     680 PE          1/15/2016   -17500                  
YESBANK     680 PE          1/18/2016   -20300                  
YESBANK     680 PE          1/19/2016   9100                    
YESBANK     700 CE          1/14/2016                       
YESBANK     700 CE          1/15/2016   2100                    
YESBANK     700 CE          1/18/2016   2800                    
YESBANK     700 CE          1/19/2016   9800                    
YESBANK     700 CE          1/12/2016   211400                  
YESBANK     700 CE          1/13/2016   -64400                  
YESBANK     700 CE          1/14/2016   119000                  
YESBANK     700 CE          1/15/2016   69300                   
YESBANK     700 CE          1/18/2016   -20300                  
YESBANK     700 CE          1/19/2016   -21700                  
YESBANK     700 PE          1/12/2016   -25900                  
YESBANK     700 PE          1/13/2016   -13300                  
YESBANK     700 PE          1/14/2016   -2800                   
YESBANK     700 PE          1/15/2016   -3500                   
YESBANK     700 PE          1/18/2016   -5600                   
YESBANK     700 PE          1/19/2016   16100                   
YESBANK     720 CE          1/12/2016   2100                    
YESBANK     720 CE          1/15/2016   1400                    
YESBANK     720 CE          1/18/2016   2100                    
YESBANK     720 CE          1/12/2016   106400                  
YESBANK     720 CE          1/13/2016   -59500                  
YESBANK     720 CE          1/14/2016   -7700                   
YESBANK     720 CE          1/15/2016   7000                    
YESBANK     720 CE          1/18/2016   9100                    
YESBANK     720 CE          1/19/2016   -58100                  
YESBANK     720 PE          1/18/2016                       
YESBANK     720 PE          1/12/2016   -3500                   
YESBANK     720 PE          1/13/2016   -2100                   
YESBANK     720 PE          1/14/2016   -1400                   
YESBANK     720 PE          1/15/2016   -2800                   
YESBANK     720 PE          1/18/2016   -2100                   
YESBANK     720 PE          1/19/2016   -4200                   
ADANIPORTS  205 PE          1/15/2016   0                   
ADANIPORTS  205 PE          1/18/2016   14400                   
ADANIPORTS  205 PE          1/19/2016   3200                    
ADANIPORTS  210 CE          1/18/2016                       
ADANIPORTS  210 CE          1/15/2016                       
ADANIPORTS  210 CE          1/18/2016   20800                   
ADANIPORTS  210 CE          1/19/2016   20000000                    
ADANIPORTS  210 PE          1/18/2016                       
ADANIPORTS  210 PE          1/19/2016   1600                    
ADANIPORTS  210 PE          1/13/2016   11200                   
ADANIPORTS  210 PE          1/14/2016   3200                    
ADANIPORTS  210 PE          1/15/2016   11200                   
ADANIPORTS  210 PE          1/18/2016   72000                   
ADANIPORTS  210 PE          1/19/2016   174400                  
ADANIPORTS  215 CE          1/13/2016                       
ADANIPORTS  215 CE          1/18/2016   14400                   
ADANIPORTS  215 CE          1/19/2016   -3200                   
ADANIPORTS  215 PE          1/18/2016                       
ADANIPORTS  215 PE          1/19/2016   1600                    
ADANIPORTS  215 PE          1/12/2016   6400                    
ADANIPORTS  215 PE          1/13/2016   9600                    
ADANIPORTS  215 PE          1/14/2016   4800                    
ADANIPORTS  215 PE          1/15/2016   -1600
```

Hi friends i have an excel data as above , for the above i want to search open interest mover for the today(here i suppose it 1/19/2016). My definition for open interest mover is open interest added on 01.19.2016 exceeds open interest on that stock in all the dates in which data is available( here data is available from 01.12.2016 to 01.19.2016(last date).The Output of the formula for the stock is mentioned in separate column shown `I` and `J`. I have data for many such stocks and new rows are getting added each day in the table. 
For example for stock named yes bank Highest open interest added is in the row E10.

Can some expert help me to write the formula for column I and J as shown.iF there is no output then formula(in case the highest open interest added today (01.09.2015) is not maximum of all the data then should print an error message as "sorry".

Thanks all

Comment: Update question with better formatting. It isnot very readable right now

Comment: http://imgur.com/VkAhbPz

Answer (score 0):

Mostly I have no idea what you really want but part of it seems to be `680` in I2 `CE` in J2, `210` in I3 and `CE` in J3 from the data in six columns on the left, which I assume start with `Stocks name` in A1. So perhaps to get you started in I2, copied across and down to suit:

```
 =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MAX(IF($A:$A=$H2,$E:$E)),$E:$E,0))
```

An array formula, so to be entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter rather thna just with Enter.